# Less then or Equal to Relation on Ordered Fields

Tags: ordered-fields

If we consider the natural numbers, we have for all $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ that $a\leq b\Longleftrightarrow (\exists x\in\mathbb{N})[a+x=b]$. (For example if $a=2$ and $b=5$ there exists $3\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2+3=5$.) Now, as a generalization of this I was trying to prove that if $(\mathbb{F},+,\cdot,\leq)$ is an ordered field, then for all $a,b\in \mathbb{F}$ we have that
\begin{align*}
a\leq b\Longleftrightarrow (\exists x\geq 0)[a+x=b].
\end{align*}

I've been using the following definitions: A field $(\mathbb{F}, +,\cdot)$ is called an ordered field iff there is an ordering relation $\leq$ on $\mathbb{F}$ such that for all $a,b,c\in \mathbb{F}$ we have
\begin{align*}
a\leq b\Longrightarrow a+c\leq b+c
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
(0\leq a)\wedge (0\leq b)\Longrightarrow 0\leq a\cdot b,
\end{align*}
where an ordering is defined as a binary relation that's reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive.

Now, how do I get from my definitions to what I'm trying to prove?

Comment: I'm aware I didn't properly state quantifiers since I thought it's obvious that $(\exists x)(\forall a,b)$ doesn't make much sense. Ok, inserting $x=b-a$ obviously works, but what about the implication $a+x=b\Rightarrow a\leq b$? Only makes sense for $0\leq x$, though.

Comment: Well, if we consider the natural numbers, we have for all $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ that $a\leq b\Longleftrightarrow (\exists x\in\mathbb{N})[a+x=b]$. (For example if $a=2$ and $b=5$ there exists $3\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2+3=5$.) Now I was trying to prove a generalized version of this for ordered fields. What I meant with $0\leq x$ in my last comment was that if $x$ is negative $a+x=b$ would result in $b\leq a$.

Comment: $\forall a,\forall b,(a\le b\Leftrightarrow \exists x\in\Bbb F, a+x=b)$ is false because for $\exists x\in \Bbb F,a+x=b$ is true when $b<a$ as well. On the other hand, $\forall a,\forall b,(a\le b\Leftrightarrow\exists x\ge 0, a+x=b)$ is true.

Comment: Ok, it clearly makes more sense now then in my initial draft. But how can we formally prove it?

Comment: Hint:  First show $b-a  \geq 0$, then use that as your $c$

Comment: From $a\leq b\Rightarrow a+c\leq b+c$ we get $a+(-a)\leq b+(-a)$ and therefore $0\leq b-a$ but I cannot follow your second thought.